# Merge two strings to shorten them

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I am working on a problem in which I need to merge two string such that one string can be inside other one. The merged string should be of shortest length.

Example:

```
str1 = "AABAK"
str2 = "HYUAABA"
merged string = "HYUAABAK"
```

So far I was able to make it work for string which are ending in similar substrings but if they are other way round, my solution isn't working.

Failing for:

```
str1 = 'ctaagt'
str2 = 'gcta'
expected answer: gctaagt
```

Solution:

```
def overlap(str1, str2):
    l = min(len(str1), len(str2))
    for i in range(l, -1, -1):
        if str1.endswith(str2[-i:]):
            print('overlap ' + str2[-i:])
            return str2[-i:]


str1 = "AABAK"
str2 = "HYUAABA"

for i in range(len(str1), -1, -1):
    res = overlap(str1[0:i], str2)
    if(res):
        print('merge ' + str2+str1[i:])
        break
```

I also want to know if there is any better or cleaner approach to solve this.

Note: str1 is on purpose shorter for my testing purpose.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `overlap` to return the final overlapped string. Then, you can consider both possible arrangements of `str1` and `str2` and choose the final result with `min` for which `key` is the length of the string:

```
def overlap(str1, str2): # best possible overlap where str1 is 1st and str2 is 2nd
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        if str2.startswith(str1[i:]):
            return str1[:i] + str2
    return str1 + str2

str1 = 'ctaagt'
str2 = 'gcta'

result = min(overlap(str1, str2), overlap(str2, str1), key=len)
print(result) # gctaagt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [tobias_k's solution from a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333771/how-can-i-merge-overlapping-strings-in-python) as reference you can do something like the following. And then just compare the output from a,b and b,a to see which resulting string is shorter.

```
from functools import reduce

a = "AABAK"
b = "HYUAABA"


def overlap(a, b):
    return max(i for i in range(len(b)) if b[i - 1] == a[-1] and a.endswith(b[:i]))


reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[overlap(a, b):], [b, a])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your overlap and do your string merge in the same loops quite simply:

```
def merge(str1, str2):
    str2_len = len(str2)
    for i in range(str2_len):
        # edited to only match correctly
        if str1.startswith(str2[i:]):
            return str2 + str1[str2_len-i:]
    return str2 + str1
```

---

> >>> str1 = "AABAK"
>
> >>> str2 = "HYUAABA"
>
> >>> merge(str1, str2)
>
> 'HYUAABAK'

---

> >>> str1 = 'ctaagt'
>
> >>> str2 = 'gcta'
>
> >>> merge(str1, str2)
>
> 'gctaagt'

Comment: The problem here is that if `str1 = 'gcta'` and `str2 = 'ctaagt'` this will give the wrong result.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry yesterday! One thing that I got wrong was that instead of checking only if the `str2` substring is in `str1`, it should be checking if the substring is in the start of `str1`. I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Also, I assume that you want to merge the two strings even if they don't overlap, what might not be wat you want to. You can change this by modifying the return.